# Eliminar caracteres de una cadena según la cantidad total encontrada

Tags: php, array, str-replace, caracteres

Estoy intentando eliminar ciertas etiquetas html dentro de una variable **$contenidoArticulos** la cual viene de un campo de la base de datos con algunas etiquetas html que no usaremos, así que en un principio metí las etiquetas a elimnar en un array para reemplazarlo por espacios en blaco y listo.

```
//Etiquetas html para eliminar desde el campo contenidos en la base de datos.

$eliminarHtml = array('<p>', "</p>", "<u>", "</u>", "<a>", "</a>","<strong>", "</strong>", "<em>", "</em>");

//Reemplazar por espacios vacios

$contenidoSinHtml = str_replace($eliminarHtml, "", $contenidoArticulos);
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, sin embargo veo que algunas de las etiquetas con enlaces largos que hay dentro del contenido no son eliminados, como por ejemplo este:

```
Artículo sobre las plantas donde.. <a href="http://www.web.com/sobre-las-plantas/a574">Título del enlace </a>
```

En ese caso ¿cómo podría eliminarlo?

Se me ha ocurrido esta opción pero no soy capaz de sacarlo:

```
//Si en el array o el contenido $contenidoArticulos existe <a href

//Contar la cantidad total de caracteres de principio a fin (desde <a href hasta >Título enlace </a>) 

//Contar la cantidad de caracteres en total
$cadenaEncontrada = '<a href=" ';
echo strlen ($cadenaEncontrada);

//Eliminar toda la cantidad total de caracteres encontrados en $cadenaEncontrada
```

¿Es posible hacer algo así?

Comment: ¿entiendo que estás en php? Utiliza las etiquetas para indicarlo

Comment: Si, es posible. [strpos](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php) La función posición de string te permite encontrar la posición en que se encuentra un código como el que mencionas, luego tienes que combinarlo con un explode o alguna función similar para separar el texto en un antes y un después de modo de encontrar el siguiente `</a>` después del `<a href=""...` una vez que tengas la posición final, puedes usar el str_replace con el texto competo o con la posición inicial y final, como gustes. Básicamente es un juego de funciones, una sobre otra.

Comment: Hola, finalmente usando esta función arreglo dicho problema.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php

$contenidoSinEtiquetas = strip_tags($contenidoArticulos);

Gracias a ambos, saludos.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finalmente usando esta función arreglo dicho problema.

[php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php)

```
$contenidoSinEtiquetas = strip_tags($contenidoArticulos);
```

Gracias a ambos por la ayuda, saludos.